# What's the best way to define a class which just to be used for one class?

Tags: scala

I defined a class for a page view, and it accepts some values to render it:

```
class LoginPage {

  val template = new Template("login")

  def render(data: LoginPage#Data):String = {
    template.apply(data)
  }

  case class Data(username:String, password:String)

}
```

When use it:

```
 val loginPage = new LoginPage
 loginPage.render(new LoginPage.Data("freewind", "123"))
```

It works, but I really don't like to use `LoginPage#Data` to define the `render()` method.

Is there any better solution to organize the code?

Answer (score 2):

You ought to put `Data` in the companion object for `LoginPage` instead of the class itself, otherwise `Data` exists for *every instance* of `LoginPage`, which can cause some unexpected results:

```
scala> val loginPage = new LoginPage
       val loginPage2 = new LoginPage

scala> val data = new loginPage.Data("freewind", "123")
       val data2 = new loginPage2.Data("freewind", "123")

scala> data == data2
res6: Boolean = false
```

Something like this would be better:

```
class LoginPage {
    val template = new Template("login")

    def render(data: LoginPage.Data):String = {
        template.apply(data)
    }
}

object LoginPage {
    case class Data(username:String, password:String)   
}
```

As for not using the full `LoginPage.Data` path, there isn't a whole lot I think you can do with it, if you really want it to be contained in the class/object. You *could* `import LoginPage._` within the class definition of `LoginPage`, so that you'd only need `Data` in the signature of `render`.

```
class LoginPage {
    import LoginPage._

    def render(data: Data): String = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make `render` take in two parameters `name`/`password`, combine them into a tuple, and pass it to `template#apply`. I don't know what the method can take in tho...

```
trait LoginPage {
  val template = new Template("login")
  def render(name: String, pw: String) = template((name, pw))
}
```